# ExecutorService invokeAll() duplicates Callable being called

Tags: java, multithreading, duplicates, executorservice, executor

I have a problem when trying to invoke a list of callables from a `fixedThreadPool`. While all the callables will execute, some of them seem to be dispatched to different threads simultaneously so they are in fact called more than once. See the code below:

```
try {
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Environment.nThreads);
    es.invokeAll(Environment.jobPool);
    es.shutdown();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not having the same task added multiple times to the collection you pass to ExecutorService? Also are you sure none of your task throw exceptions during their run?

Comment: Hard to imagine the problem is in this piece of code. How is `Environment.jobPool` constructed?

Comment: This is the piece of code where jobPool is created
    public static final ArrayList<Callable<Object>> jobPool = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
This is where the jobs are added to it:
    Environment.jobPool.add(Executors.callable(new Job(eval, validator)));
@Andrei I don't see how a callable would be called twice even when throwing an exception. I don't think they did anyway as I tend to print all exceptions in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably duplicated some of your `Callable` tasks in the list. Try using a `java.util.Set` implementing properly the `equal` method of every `Callable` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If a Callable throws an uncaught exception the behaviour is undefined. For interrupted exception in stops the ExecutorService for example. Also, since incokeAll accepts a Collection , build a HashSet out of your ArrayList and pass it that just to make sure you don't have anything duplicated

```
Set<?> set = new HashSet<?>(jobPool);
```

I'm pretty sure the ExecutorService doesn't just call the same Callable twice.